# Why Bot application is In-Review status?

Tags: botframework

Who is responsible for reviewing the bot publication and how long does they take to review and approve my bot?

Comment: This may not be the appropriate place to get an answer to that. Perhaps somewhere in [Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/) or the [Microsoft Forums](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/) is a more likely place to get help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a large backlog of bots currently being reviewed by the Bot Framework team.  It's worth noting however, that the only thing that this approval does is to include your bot in the official Bot Framework directory.  You do not need your bot reviewed by the Bot Framework in order to be live on any of the channels.

That being said, many of the channels have their own review processes (such as Facebook, Kik, Slack, etc.) Some (like Facebook) require review before any 3rd party can contact your bot.  Others (like Slack and Kik) require review to list in their directory or auto-complete in @mentions. You'll need to apply for review from each of these channels.

Comment: I made a simple skype chatting bot and how could i make my bot live? So that my friends can able to use it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your bot already is live and your friends can use it; you just have to share the join link with them for the chat service you want them to use (look in the embed codes section).  The bot directory just lets you share it more broadly than friends.

Comment: Can't they just use my bot name to search it in Skype and find it?